# Controller variable doesn't get displayed right in html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, socket.io

I'm trying to make a selection dropdown list from data extracted from database, in order to choose a certain date my html is :

```
<div>
        <div>Select Year</div>
        <select class="browser-default" data-ng-model="year">
          <option ng-repeat="year in years">{{year}}</option>
        </select>
        <div>Select Month</div>
        <select  class="browser-default" data-ng-model="month"  ng-options="month.id as month.name for month in months" ></select>
        <a class="btn waves-effect waves-light blue darken-1 right bout2" ng-click="changeDate(month, year)">Confirm</a>
      </div>
```

and in my controller:

```
socket.emit('Question', {
       // SQL to get the years from database
    });
socket.on('response', function (data){

            $scope.years =data.rep;
            $scope.year = "2016";
});
$scope.list_months = {"months":[{"id":"01","name":"Janvier"},{"id":"02","name":"Fevrier"},{"id":"03","name":"Mars"},{"id":"04","name":"Avril"},{"id":"05","name":"Mai"},{"id":"06","name":"Juin"},{"id":"07","name":"Juillet"},{"id":"08","name":"Aout"},{"id":"09","name":"Septembre"},{"id":"10","name":"Octobre"},{"id":"11","name":"Novembre"},{"id":"12","name":"Decembre"}]};
    $scope.months = $scope.list_months.months;
```

the output of the months are working perfectly and also gets initialized easily by assining a value to $scope.month, however it's an other story for the years, when I refresh the app sometimes the list appears and other times it doesn't (the dropdown list is empty) .
Since it appears correctly that means that the problem is not in SQL but what makes it disappear ?? Could you please help me find out what I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you're doing a request to get the years, so it will be `null` initially. Are you sure the request isn't just taking a long time or erroring?

Comment: @Rhumborl there is no error in SQL in the server, when I refresh sometimes it appears right and sometimes the list is empty, but when I do console.log() the console shows the result so it's not the problem of the query I guess

Comment: looks like you are using socket.io client? I assume `socket` is a raw socket.io object, not some angular-wrapped plugin or anything?

Comment: @Rhumborl yes you are right socket.io is raw but the result is shown in the console even though it's not displayed in html so I'm assuming that it's not the problem ? is there a kind of wait I could do ? maybe the html is launched before the data is returned to the $scope variable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting `$scope.years` in the event handler for the socket.io object. This is triggered from an external source outside of Angular, which means it is unaware of the change and so will not run a [`$digest()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest) to update the page.

You need to manually call [`$scope.$apply()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) after setting the `years` and `year` properties:

```
socket.on('response', function (data){
    $scope.years = data.rep;
    $scope.year = "2016";
    $scope.$apply();
});
```

It may occasionally seem to be working because another action on the page *is* causing Angular to run a `$digest()`, and the years dropdown gets re-rendered as a side effect of that.